# What's the difference between () and {} in javascript functions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

These functions seem to get used interchangeably in React tutorials but can't figure out the difference... or when to use which?

```
const SomeVal = () => {
    ...
}

const SomeVal = () => (
    ...
)
```

Comment: the first one you replace ... with code that your function should run.

Comment: I assume you're referring to arrow functions (`() => {}` or `() => ()`). The former creates a block so the arrow function can have multiple statements. The latter is an implicit return of an expression wrapped in the grouping operator.

Comment: This is a question I to would like to know the answer to.

Comment: @Li357 you should make that an answer as it's the answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These are fundamentally different. The former arrow function syntax, `() => {}`, allows you to have multiple statements inside the arrow function's body, i.e.:

```
() => {
  console.log('Hello!');
  return 'World!';
}
// When called, this logs Hello! and returns World!
```

But the latter, `() => ()`, is an arrow function *that implicitly returns* an expression that is wrapped in parentheses (called the grouping operator). It does not explicitly allow for multiple statements:

```
() => (
  'World' // only one expression that is implicitly returned
  // Would work fine without parentheses (unless you want to return an object!)
)
// When called, this function returns 'World'
```

Of course, you could also create an unreadable arrow function that performs multiple operations using the comma operator:

```
() => (console.log('Hello!'), 'World!')
```

#### React

I assume you see this with React stateless components:

```
const Comp = () => (
  <div>Hello World!</div>
);
```

This function (components are just functions) returns the `<div>` element implicitly. But, using `{}`, you can do some intermediary calculations instead of just returning right away:

```
const Comp = () => {
  const msg = 'Hello World!';
  return ( // Need to explicitly return here
    <div>{msg}</div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Not that much less readable IMO with formatting, especially if it's only a few statements. I agree probably not practical in production code, but useful for golfing/fun

Answer (score 2):

An [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) with `const fn = () => { ... }` creates a code block where you can have multiple lines of code. However for this case you **need** to have a return statement.

An arrow function with `const fn = () => ( ... );` supports a single line of code and the return statement is implicit. The brackets around the function are optional so your function could look like

```
const sum = (a, b) => a + b;
const sum2 = (a, b) => (a + b);

const sumBlock = (a, b) => { return a + b; }
```

In essence, both do the same thing. But, the latter way of writing arrow functions allows your code to be slightly more concise if you only need a single statement.

Comment: Note that you can also have multiple lines when using `()`, comma separated with the last item being what is returned (no `return` statement). See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator